# How can I get the actual absolute path of an executable that was found via %PATH% in Windows (PowerShell)?

Tags: powershell, path

When I open a PowerShell window and type an executable file name in order to run it, I expect the actual executable to be found among the folders specified in `%PATH%` (`$Env:Path` in pwsh) environment variable in Windows.
Is there a way to retrieve the actual absolute path of the executable that is (or will be) run for a certain file name? I though of something like:

```
Get-EnvPath msbuild.exe
```

that will return something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: for powershell try `get-command <command>` and for CMD try `where <command>` https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-which-equivalent-cmd-powershell/

Comment: Without knowing what your attempting to do, and why you need the absolute path of an executable that is otherwise found, you would use the .NET cop ability to confirm a File actually exists.  You can do that by parsing the system variables until you find the path the executable will be in

Comment: as FrankThomas pointed out, the `Get-Command` cmdlet will provide that info. for instance, this >>> `(Get-Command notepad.exe).Path` <<< will give you this >>> `C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe` <<<

Comment: @FrankThomas, that's what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your question and tried to elaborate a simple solution without any fancy dot net classes. Good old pure powershell ;-).

It should work anywhere, where the environment variable "path" is available and powershell (5.x, Core, 7) is installed, even on unixoid system e.g. linux, mac OS and so on, though there are some caveats.

```
Function Get-EnvPath {
    param (
        [string]$filename
    )
    $env:Path -split ";" | Where-Object {
        Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath $filename)  -PathType Leaf
    } | ForEach-Object {
        Return (Join-Path -Path $_ -ChildPath $filename)
    }
}
```

This script would return any ocurrence of the searched filename in the folders contained in path variable, thus giving us more flexibility in selecting what we wan't to execute  instead of just typing the executables name to the cli or our script and relying on the systems (windows) firstmatch principle. Unfortunately i don't know how linux handles the same task.

```
Sample Output:
==============

PS C:\testDir\> Get-EnvPath -filename notepad.exe
C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe <---- first  match
C:\Windows\notepad.exe          <---- second match
```

To be absolutely sure, an executable listed (found) by the user, can also be executed  by the user, we would have to check several properties and flags of the found files. Mainly speaking of the ACL's read and execute permissions under Windows. Under linux either check the files' access properties (d-rwx-rwx-rwx) or the ACL.

But be careful, some executables in linux just ignore ACL's and rely only on the files acces properties.